# Topological properties via properties continuous maps

Tags: gn.general-topology

A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is connected if and only if the only continuous maps $f:X\to\{0,1\}$ (where $\{0,1\}$ carries the discrete topology) are the constant maps.

Are there other examples of topological properties that can be discribed via topological properties of continuous maps? (I apologize for the somewhat fuzzy nature of this question.)

Comment: All of them can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous examples and it's not too difficult to come up with a few on your own, but here is a few examples:

A topological space $X$ is said to be functionally Hausdorff if and only if  each pair of distinct points of $X$ can be separated by a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow [0,1].$

Another would be to say that a topological space $X$ is $T_0$ if and only if each initial source at $X$ is point separating.

A space $X$ is totally disconnected if and only if each continuous map from a connected space into $X$ is constant.

A space $X$ is connected if and only if every continuous map from $X$ into any totally disconnected space is constant.

Comment: What is an "initial source at $X$"?

Answer (score 3):

In a way this is precisely what the theory of classifying spaces is about. For example the cohomology group $H^1(X)$ corresponds to homotopy equivalence classes of continuous maps from $X$ to $K(\pi,1)$ where $\pi$ is the fundamental group.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few examples based on the lifting property in the category of topological spaces. For example, see answers there
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434312/are-there-useful-categorical-characterisations-of-the-topological-separation-axioms

But there are also other examples, see http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.6710.pdf
or more examples in [an unfinished update.](http://mishap.sdf.org/by:gavrilovich/mints-lifting-property-as-negation-DMG_5_no_4_dec_2014.pdf)